# Getting "constructor(opt_error) {" error in error.js while running test in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am getting

> constructor(opt_error) {" error in my error.js under C:\Users\ ######
>   \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js

```
class WebDriverError extends Error {
  /** @param {string=} opt_error the error message, if any. */
  **constructor(opt_error) {**
    super(opt_error);

  /** @override */
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
}
```

Any comment or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. This is happening because chrome driver is out of date and it is not compatible with new chrome updates. Therefore webdriver is unable to create sessions with chrome. So you have to update your chrome driver to the latest version. I did uninstall the protractor and then reinstall it and webdriver.

```
npm install -g protractor
npm install -g webdriver-manager
```

Then I did update the webdriver so it installed the latest version of chrome driver(2.53.0).

```
webdriver-manager update
```

Then I ran webdriver again using,

```
webdriver-manager start
```

And it's worked fine.